# Oven probe thermistor inoperative

Tags: oven

The "meat thermometer" oven probe in our GE JB970SB1SS home range doesn't seem to be working. Ohming out the probe, it appears to be a thermistor with a resistance of around 57 kOhms at room temperature. Is there any way to find specs for this probe to determine whether it is the defective component? I think the probe is part number WB20T10024 but I'm not sure.

Comment: While waiting for possible data, try putting it in hot water and see what the resistance is then.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the probe works after all; I'm not sure what was wrong. I did have to twist the connector back and forth a few times to get a good connection and reading. Anyway, in the meantime I did the science experiment of measuring the resistance vs temperature for this probe.

[image: Characterizing the thermister]

Here's the data:

```
T:  41.4, 80.9,  108.5, 118.0, 135.0, 142.4, 148.7, 156.7, 166.0, 176.0    °F
R: 158.9, 44.64, 22.78, 16.31, 13.20, 10.07,  8.37,  7.00, 5.673, 4.827  kOhm
```

Comment: You may want to give the probe's plug a light scuffing with some steel wool, and also use the steel wool inside the plug in the oven. If there's any corrosion in there (and it sounds like there might be), the steel wool should be flexible enough to get into the socket, yet rough enough to do the job. Just make sure you get it all out, or you'll leave a dead short in there, and that's not good at all.